# PHP Javascript HTML2PDF HIGHCHARTS image

Tags: javascript, php, pdf, highcharts, html2pdf

I am trying to export my graphs generated by Highcharts to a pdf report by using HTML2PDF. I understood that HTML2PDF doesn't manage well javascript and the solution can be to save your generated graphic as image and use these images to generate the pdf. That's what I am trying to do.
I tried to do that but the in output I have an error saying:`Unable to get the size of the image []`
Does anyone know how to solve this issue. Here's my php script:

```
...
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

        var options = {
    title: {
        text: 'Monthly Average Temperature',
        x: -20 //center
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com',
        x: -20
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
                     'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Temperature (°C)'
        },
        plotLines: [{
            value: 0,
            width: 1,
            color: '#808080'
        }]
    },
    tooltip: {
        valueSuffix: '°C'
    },
    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'middle',
        borderWidth: 0
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Tokyo',
        data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
    }, {
        name: 'New York',
        data: [-0.2, 0.8, 5.7, 11.3, 17.0, 22.0, 24.8, 24.1, 20.1, 14.1, 8.6, 2.5]
    }, {
        name: 'Berlin',
        data: [-0.9, 0.6, 3.5, 8.4, 13.5, 17.0, 18.6, 17.9, 14.3, 9.0, 3.9, 1.0]
    }, {
        name: 'London',
        data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8]
    }]
};


// URL to Highcharts export server
var exportUrl = 'http://export.highcharts.com/';

// POST parameter for Highcharts export server
var object = {
    options: JSON.stringify(options),
    type: 'image/png',
    async: true
};

// Ajax request
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: exportUrl,
    data: object,
    success: function (data) {
        // Update "src" attribute with received image URL
        $('#chart').attr('src', exportUrl + data);
    }
});
        </script>
</head>
<body>
<img id="chart" style="width: 600px;" />
<?php
$content = ob_get_clean();

    // convert
    //require_once('html2pdf.class.php');
   require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/vendor/autoload.php';

    use Spipu\Html2Pdf\Html2Pdf;
    use Spipu\Html2Pdf\Exception\Html2PdfException;
    use Spipu\Html2Pdf\Exception\ExceptionFormatter;

    try
    {
        $html2pdf = new Html2Pdf('P', 'A4', 'fr');
        $html2pdf->pdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
        $html2pdf->writeHTML($content, isset($_GET['vuehtml']));
        ob_end_clean();
        $html2pdf->Output('TestReport.pdf');
    }
    catch(HTML2PDF_exception $e) {
        echo $e;
        exit;
    }
?>
</body>
</html>
```